# Ploop snapshot is in old format

Tags: backup, virtualization, snapshot, openvz

When I try to make snapshot of my ploop container I have an error:

```
# vzctl snapshot $VEID --skip-suspend

Creating snapshot {6ea44de0-68ff-4044-9264-3dc7e818200d}
Storing /vz/private/ploop/$VEID/Snapshots.xml.tmp
Error in is_old_snapshot_format (snapshot.c:39): Snapshot is in old format
Failed to create snapshot: Error in is_old_snapshot_format (snapshot.c:39): Snapshot is in old format [38]
Failed to create snapshot
```

But there are no any snapshots:

```
# vzctl snapshot-list 2045
PARENT_UUID                            C UUID                                   DATE                NAME
```

So, I have found [just one same question](http://users.openvz.narkive.com/DMWM3CwH/snapshot-is-in-old-format) about this problem, but is not answered.

I think, it is related to updated vzctl and ploop, while container created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

It is related to ploop version, which used in creation of ploop device and its TopSnapshot.

So, we need to update ploop to recreate its TopSnapshot.

For example:

- online openvz6:

  vzctl set $VEID --diskspace $SIZE --save
- offline ploop:

  ploop resize -s $SIZE DiskDescriptor.xml